# Sequelize model not bringing LONGTEXT type fields after querying on mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

There is Story model which has different attributes,3 of them are of type LONGTEXT to save the space i have shown only 2 of them

```
detail: {
  type: Sequelize.TEXT
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.TEXT
}
```

Here is my database column types of the same fields
[image]

When i do query on story model i am getting all the fields except the detail and title. Below is screen shot of my consoled story object after querying it to db
[image]

I have tried different options but i can't see, title and detail fields on story object and i can't process it's values.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "bringing"? The record shown is a user object.

Comment: I am expecting a simple property of 'title' and 'detail' which is not there :-)

Comment: What's shown in the very hard to read screenshot (please use plain-text whenever possible) is some kind of user record, not a story record.

Comment: Exactly it's my bad. I mapped two wrong models. I will try to delete this question. Thanks for replying @Tadman

Comment: So long as you got it working, that's what counts!